# Chrome Dev Tools - How to view and manipulate css media queries?

Tags: css, mobile, google-chrome-devtools

In the styles section of Chrome Developer Tools, how do I get the @media queries to show? Everything I find talks about how to show the media queries in the window using the ellipses, but nothing about how to make the @media show in the Styles section so I can play with it there. How do I make them show?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose an element/class that has the media query as part of its css. If the element/class doesn't have a media query as part of its css, it can't show it if it isn't there.